# Meaning of the phrase "span of vectors contains"

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean if someone says the "span of vectors" $\{(x,y,z),(a,b,c)\}$ contains the vector $(d,e,f)$? I am making up numbers here. Let me know if I need to insert actual numbers here to clarify.

Comment: Did they give you a definition of the span of a sequence of vectors? (The span is a certain, usually infinite, set of vectors). The definition should answer your question.

Comment: It means that if you slap together the vectors {(x,y,z),(a,b,c)} by adding or subtracting some scalar multiple of each, then you can create the vector (d,e,f). That is to say, (d,e,f) is a linear combination of your vectors. It's like a recipe... Two parts (1,0,0) and minus one part (0,1,0) makes a (2,-1,0).

Comment: @zahbaz I thought that you could only add some scalar multiple as that's the definition of a linear combination (combination means adding right?). I did not know that you could subtract some scalar multiple. Could you explain more on subtracting scalar multiples?

Comment: A scalar can be negative. If your vector space is over the reals, then the scalars you can choose from are any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. (But perhaps my earlier comment was a bit innacurate. Adding scalars is what is necessary... scalars, though, can be negative. I loosely stated that you can add/subtract, because I'm used to working with physical spaces. I think that's alright though.)

Comment: @Dan Since you do know the definition of linear combination, the definition of the span of a certain list of vectors is simply the set of all their linear combinations. Showing that $(d,e,f)$ belongs to that span is therefore the same as showing that $(d,e,f)$ is (=can be written as) such a linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

It means that there exist scalars $\lambda,\mu$ such that
$$ \lambda x + \mu a = d, \lambda y + \mu b = e, \lambda z + \mu c = f
$$
or, equivalently
$$ \lambda\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}
+ \mu\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} d \\ e \\ f \end{bmatrix}
$$
That is, $[d,e,f]$ is a **linear combination** of $[x,y,z]$ and $[a,b,c]$.